# How to execute javascript returned from PageMethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval, pagemethods

I have page, where I'm making an ajax call to `PageMethod`, and as a result I'm getting some html string, which I need to append to some div. Now Html string has some javascript code in it, so I expect this js code to execute, after I append html to div. But the problem is, I'm getting error saying that - `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Access is denied.`, this error gets thrown when globalEval method tries to execute.

This is an ajax call I make

```
var data ={id: id};

$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "/srv/Loader.aspx/LoadUserControl",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
       $('#TargetDivID').html(data.d);
    },
    error: function (error) {
       $('#TargetDivID')..html("Control can not be loaded");
       console.log("LOG: Exeption trying to load Control:\n" + error.responseText);
    }
});
```

Here is the Html returned by WebMethod:

```
<div class="someclass" id="inHouseAdModule" style="display:none;">
Some Html Content
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Some logic goes here
        });
    </script>

</div>
```

Any ideas how can I fix this ?

**EDIT:**

```
 <div class="someclass" id="inHouseAdModule" style="display:none;">
    Some Html Content
        <script type="text/javascript">            
                Some logic goes here            
        </script>
 </div>
```

**Does not work as well.**

**EDIT:**
I've added debugger at the beginning of JS code, but exception was thrown before reaching that point.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   debugger;           
   Some logic goes here            
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have control over the returned HTML/JS? Could you for example break it up in to one JS section and one HTML section? I'm not sure whether the document ready event will even fire for your JS to work since it likely already fired before the AJAX call took place. Maybe someone else can confirm the behaviour in this case.

Comment: I've updated the post, please take a look. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After searching your error, the general consensus is that you probably have an incorrect URL in your request.  If the web method accepts GET, try to hit the URL in your browser to make sure you have it right.  Additionally, you can check the network traffic with your browser's developer tools to make sure your request and the response has the expected headers.

============================================================

Additionally

The document is likely already ready. Change your HTML to the following to execute the JavaScript immediately.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> /*Some logic goes here*/ </script>
```

If you need to call it again later, keep the function wrapper and call the function right after its declaration.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function MyFunc() { Some logic goes here } MyFunc(); </script>
```

============================================================

An Alternative Approach

Instead of loading dynamically created content via AJAX and trying to inject it onto your page, I recommend using an HTML IFRAME that points to a URL that returns the dynamically crated content.  This is a common approach for advertisement content.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I've already tried this, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm getting back expected results in success function of my ajax call, I just can't execute js code.

Comment: @Gev, have you tried running in an alternate browser?  That should help determine if it is a browser configuration issue.  It may yield better error messages as well.

Comment: @Gev, try it without wrapping your HTML with JSON.  Send it by itself with a content type of 'text/html'.  Then just shove the response text of the AJAX call right into the DIV.

Comment: 10x Malgaur, tried, didn't help :(
It seems this is happening when some AJAX calls are made simultaneously. What do you think?

Comment: The same in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @Gev, I am afraid that I am out of ideas without sitting down at the code myself.  What about a workaround?  I personally try to avoid script injection.  Is it possible in your scenario to have the JavaScript function sent over on load and then have the AJAX call receive data for the function to operate on instead of sending a dynamically crated function?  This is my preferred approach.

Comment: I've figured out something: In loaded js code a lot of external functions are being called. Here what I've found in one of them :
document.write('<SCR' + 'IPT language="JavaScript" src="http://someURL" type="text/javascript"></scr' + 'ipt>');
And here the exception is thrown!

Comment: @Gev, check the information in my answer against that piece as well.  e.g. Make sure your browser can hit the provided URL.

Comment: @Malgayr, I've found some kind of solution. Exactly, the js from this src contains `document.write()` as well, and here it goes wrong. I've changed `document.write()` like this:

 `var js = document.createElement("script");
      js.src = 'http://someUrl'; 
      var sHolder = document.getElementById(scriptContainer);
      if (sHolder != null) {
        sHolder.appendChild(js);
      }`

But still a have problem. Please take a look at this post of mine : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dynamically-loading-external-js-file-or-it-s-content#14737000003577726

Comment: @Gev, In light of the information from the thread you posted, I recommend using an IFRAME as an alternative.  See my updated answer.